# MySQL dump with only part of data

Tags: mysql

I need to create mysql dump from 2 DB for testing purposes. That DBs has a lot of data inside, so their dumps are 20 Gb each. Is it possible to create mysqldump only for 100 row from every table in each DB?

Comment: No such option. Dump partial data from each separate table using SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE. Aviod related records loose (use complex SELECTs). Or make a copy of the database with partial data then dump it.

Comment: It could be quite complex maintaining any sort of database integrity if you have FK's in place

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to mysqldump for adding a `LIMIT`, but what you may be able to approximate it with `--where="id <= '100'"`.